# Difference between using a ML docker image and running pip install in Dockerfile

Tags: python, docker, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch

I see there are many available Docker images for popular ML frameworks such as [PyTorch](https://hub.docker.com/r/pytorch/pytorch) and [Tensorflow](https://hub.docker.com/r/tensorflow/tensorflow/).

What is the difference between using these pre-built images vs installing these libraries using `pip install` or `conda install` in the Dockerfile?

I usually build my custom Docker images from an `nvidia/cuda` base image which supports GPU and later run a bash command to install my `requirements.txt` file which contain the afore-mentioned libraries. Example:

```
FROM nvidia/cuda:10.2-cudnn7-runtime-ubuntu18.04

...

# Activate virtual environment and install requirements
RUN /bin/bash -c "cd src \
    && source activate my_venv \
    && pip install -r requirements.txt"
```

I feel that using `pip install` gives me more liberties and allows me to choose a base image that enables GPU-usage with my favorite OS. I guess that it might have to do with performance issues.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference, using a pre-built image saves you from misconfiguring the docker environment or the missing dependencies and ensuring a safer execution (the whole point of docker I say). Your approach is fine in case you want to have a full control on the image being built.